# Extract number between a string and other string in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this: `meetingDes32-2` (or `meetingDes55-5` or `meetingDes354-74`, for example). What I need is to extract the number between the text `meetingDes` and `-2`. In these 3 examples what I need are: 32, 55 and 354.

I'm new to regular expressions.

Thank you.

Comment: is the number always between "meetingDes" and the "-" ?

Comment: Do your strings contain *only* `meetingDes32-2` etc, or is this part of a larger string?

Comment: yes Boann the tex is fixed the only part that can change is the numbers 32-2 or 42-25 and what i need is the first part of numbers before in this case "-2" and "-25"

Comment: `(?<=meetingDes)\\d+(?=-)` or `meetingDes(\\d+)-`

Comment: @AvinashRaj if someone is new to regular expressions, then it might be wiser to ask questions in plaintext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your strings contain nothing else, just replace the bits you don't want with nothing, and use what remains:

```
String s = "meetingDes32-2";
int num = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("meetingDes|-.*", ""));
System.out.println(num); // 32
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach if you find regexes hard:

```
int end = indexOf('-');
int startIndex = 10;
String result = meetingDesString.substring(startIndex ,end);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=meetingDes)\\d+\\b
```

This should do it for you.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/22